# Determine category in CMS block

Tags: magento

I've got some categories in Magento which have got "Static block and products" as display mode. All these categories point to the same CMS block, which in turn points to a template file. The template file should generate different content according to the category.

So my question is: Can I, in the CMS block (or template file), somehow find out the category?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `echo $this->getCategory()->getId();` in your template file?

Comment: Yeah, I get a fatal error on the getId() function.

Comment: Try this: `Mage::registry('current_category');` and check if it has current category values..

Comment: Ahh, that did actually work. You'd have posted that as an answer instead ;-) Thanks!

Comment: I'm moving it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mage::registry('current_category');
```